# Why is my new OnePlus One lack of options?

Tags: cyanogenmod, settings, 5.1-lollipop, oneplus-one

I already have a OnePlus One phone and I'm trying to configure a new one for a friend.  Both of the devices are updated to the version `cm-12.1-yog4pas2ql-bacon` and also have root.

But for some reason my phone has a lot more options in the menus.  For instance, I want to remove the camera and dialer shortcuts from the lock screen.

<sub>(Click image to enlarge; hover to know description)</sub>

[image: IMG: My phone] [image: IMG: My friend's phone]

Does anyone know what's causing this?

Comment: I believe this is because your phone has CM12 and your friend has COS12. Are you sure both phones have same OS ?

Comment: @Manubhargav Yes I'm sure of it https://i.imgur.com/k2ZT7yI.png

Answer (score 0):

Thankfully, Manubhargav [directed my attention](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/127542/why-is-my-new-oneplus-one-lack-of-options#comment158120_127542) to the "About Phone" section, and there was an option which I didn't remember that has existed, the option "Advanced mode" was turned off.

<sub>(Click image to enlarge)</sub>

[image: IMG:]